# How to retrieve the third-party library licenses

Tags: licensing, open-source, builds, maven, gradle

I am looking for a way to automatically collect all the third-party library licences that my project is using. Currently I am collecting by hand the licences on github.

So far , I don't have a clear idea how to get a 3rd party library licence automatically.
What is the most reliable way to get the 3rd party licence ?

Small ideas :

- Most **Github** projects contain a licence text. ex : https://github.com/square/dagger . But can you map a dependency 
  'com.squareup.dagger:dagger:1.2.2' with its github url ?
- most JVM artifacts are found on **mvnrepository** . I don't know if mvnrepository.com list the licence.
- the .jar files may contain licence text . How to extract it ?

Related :
[What is the best practice for arranging third-party library licenses "paperwork"?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/234511/what-is-the-best-practice-for-arranging-third-party-library-licenses-paperwork)

Comment: What you are looking for doesn't exist, there is no best practice. You have to do it by hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible way to automate part of this is the following algorithm:

```
Add the project GAV to queue
For each GAV in queue 
  Add all dependencies from GAV to queue // optional after first run? 
  Download jar
  Extract/unzip jar and search root directory of jar for file containing "license" // see Java zip classes
  Parse root pom.xml for license information
  if neither work
     output that license information could NOT be found
  else
     save license information for GAV
// end for loop
```

You could create a maven plugin that does this and outputs the file to the root directory of your project (instead of a build directory) so that you notice when the file changes. Otherwise, a perl/python script might be easier (but also more of a hack.. :) ).

Given that it's easy to use transitive dependencies in your code without knowing it, you should also look at using the the [Ban Transitive Dependencies](https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/banTransitiveDependencies.html) enforcer rule.

If you do not do that, then I would definitely make sure to scan all transitive dependencies for their licenses (always use the 3rd line of the algorithm).

Comment: Thanks Marco for pointing the Transitive Dependencies. I listed the .jar containing the licence but most projects' pom.xml don't contain licence info.